# Joomla extensions for photo albums

Tags: php, joomla, content-management-system, joomla1.7

I need a photo album extension for Joomla that can take selected folders from the file manager and show each one of them as an album. It should have a module that can show for example 6 albums which when clicked on can open the album's page and display pictures from that album in whatever way. Something like [SIMGallery](http://www.simbunch.com/demos/simgallery?view=latestalbums) but for Joomla 1.7, it has a module for showing random albums, that's exactly what I need. It's a shame it's only available for Joomla 1.5.

The thing is I have pretty much no experience in Joomla. I have no problem in learning it but I can't find decent tutorials that teach how to make components or modules. The web is filled with WordPress tutorials but finding a good article for Joomla is extremely hard.

If there are available extensions out there, please link me, that would be great but I would really like to make something on my own also. Can someone guide to nice articles for component and module development and understand the J platform. A good starting point for Joomla 1.7.

Thanks! I appreciate all the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the list of [photo gallery plugins](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/photos-a-images/photo-gallery) on the Joomla Extensions Directory - there should be at least one with your requirements. Also, I have some [Joomla tutorials](http://www.virtuosimedia.com/tags/joomla-tutorials) on my site. I don't have a module or component tutorial up yet (they're planned), but I have installation and template tutorials that you might find useful.

You may find it difficult to find tutorials for Joomla 1.6 or 1.7 as the Joomla team is now moving through version numbers at a faster rate than the past. However, if you find something for Joomla 1.5, chances are that it will work for later versions as well with just a few minor adjustments (usually the install XML file).

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I really like your template tutorial, very helpful. Anyway I found one extension called SIMGallery, it's exactly what I need, but it is only available for 1.5 Native. I've updated my question with a link to SIMGallery. If you know something similar please let me know. Thanks!